# Isi cream whipper head valve sticks open

Tags: cream, whipper

I have an isi 1/2 liter cream whipper which I purchased in 2010. It has worked well until recently when the head valve began sticking open. I purchased a new head valve, but the problem remains. It has been thoroughly cleaned and also has a new lid gasket.

I tried to use it today for the first time with the new valve. When I first dispensed some cream, it seemed fine, but when I released the lever, cream continued to ooze out. The valve was not returning to the closed position. This is what it was doing with the old valve. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks again. As soon as I cleaned everything (again ), the new valve is no longer sticking.

Answer (score 1):

[Have you disassembled and cleaned it?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B95Kelv9zRE) The valve comes apart. A small brush (which comes with a new whipper) can be used to clean the inside. Make sure the o-rings are clean and viable. Make sure you reassemble securely.  The head needs regular cleaning for proper functioning.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try. Not sure why the new one has the same problem, but anyway, we'll see what happens.